# How to reset my program (close.. and Open again) - Windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to reset my program (close.. and Open again)

in C# windows-mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a WinMo cmdline project in your solution and use  Process.Start(appPath + @"\yourprogram.exe", String.Empty);  (you can use Thread.sleep too before the Process.Start) in your main program use Application.Exit and after that use a Process.Start to the loader application. Maybe pass bye a parameter too then from the loader application cannot start your app only if you do it from your code and pass that "key" to the other app.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The only way it can be done is making an exit in program after placing a request in some task-scheduler to start it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to have scheduler for that.
Then Perform cocreateinstence, then set the parameters, then save the task..
application triggers when the scheduler runs..

Answer (score 0):

[P/Invoke CeRunAppAtTime](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/CeRunAppAtTime.html) with yourself as the target and 11 seconds in the future as a time, then exit the app.

Comment: Interesting downvote.  How else would you propose to do this?